# EmberJS: Injecting owner to native class from component

Tags: javascript, class, ember.js

The thing i'm trying to do, is to inject owner to my JS native class in Ember(3.15.0).
It looks something like this:

```
  component.ts

  export default class ClassOne extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super(...arguments);
      const myClass = new ClassTwo();
      ...
    }
  }

  ClassTwo.ts

  export default class ClassTwo {
    @service() someService: ServiceType;
    ...
  }
```

Because of that, on someService, i'm getting expectable `Attempting to lookup an injected property on an object without a container, ensure that the object was instantiated via a container`

I've seen similar questions that were solved by using `getOwner(this).ownerInjection()` but those were all based on `Class.create()` that was extended by Ember.Object.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this in modern Ember is to use `setOwner`.

```js
import { setOwner } from '@ember/application';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class MyClass {
  @service myService;
  
  constructor(owner) {
    setOwner(this, owner);
    this.appName = this.myService.appName;
  }
}
```

See it working here: https://ember-twiddle.com/e6481c33c3150e3418606e79decaed78?openFiles=classes.my-class%5C.js%2C

See documentation for `setOwner` here:

https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.22/functions/@ember%2Fapplication/setOwner

This answer should work in Ember 3.15+ and is current as of Ember 3.23.

By the way, that error message could really use an update from container -> owner

Comment: Looks like it's working great, thank You!. Is it legit to use setOwner for this kind of issues? I'm asking as there are barely any mentiones of it around internet and documentation for it is quite poor.

Comment: As it is public api, I think it is quite legit to use. As to better documentation, I would ask on dev-learning-team channel on the Ember Discord.

Comment: It's sort of an advanced feature, no I'm not surprised about the lack of talking about it. But at every project / job I've seen, it is common to see something using setOwner

Comment: Great discussion. Is there a way to `setOwner` via initializer (maybe an instance one?), instead of having to pass the `owner` to the constructor in every instantiation?